# CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo: No duration?

Tags: avfoundation, avassetwriter, cmsamplebufferref

I have a live stream, and `CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo` gives a duration with `CMTime(value=0, timescale=0)` for video.

For audio, I get 1024 samples at once, but `CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(sampleBuffer, index, &timingInfo)` gives the exact same presentationTimeStamp for every single index in the sample.

How can I accurately get duration info during a live stream for video frames, and how can I get the actual time of an audio sample in a `CMSampleBufferRef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only rely on `presentationTimeStamp`s, so you can't know the duration of the current video frame until the next frame arrives. This makes sense for a live stream, as capture frame rates are variable and depend on lighting, etc, but this also seems to be true when the sample buffers come from a file.

The duration can be calculated like so:

```
CMTimeSubtract(timingInfoNext.presentationTimeStamp, timingInfoCurrent.presentationTimeStamp)
```

Comment: I guess this makes sense, but it makes other math harder. The average duration between frames may be enough for my needs.